# My SVG file shows as a blank icon on the desktop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm a new at the web design and I'm not sure if I've done right thing while saving my icon as svg file. Here's the thing - I got an outline icon and when I save it as svg with options shown in attached file, the icon of the file on my desktop is shown as a blank paper with folded edge and no program can open it. When previewing the svg file in the browsers everything looks great. I'm concerd why does it's icon on the my desktop doesn't look as every other svg file...Will my svg file work anyway?

Thanks in the advance![image]

Comment: What operating system are you on? Desktop icons may not support SVG.

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: If your icons look like the image has to do with your operating system (as @Takkat said). The important thing is that you should be able to open the SVG in your programs (for example Illustrator for editing and Chrome for viewing it).

Comment: The svg file looks completely fine in any browser, it is responsive and with good sharpness. It opens in Illustrator only when I use Open with>Illustrator so I guess you are right. It must be the operating system's fault. I didn't know that. Thank you very much, folks!

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnail preview in Windows Explorer is not supported for SVG files. To be able to get a preview we can install a shell extension, e.g. the [SVG Explorer Extension](https://svgextension.codeplex.com/) (courtesy of [this post on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/342052/how-to-get-svg-thumbnails-in-windows-explorer)).

To open an SVG per default (on mouse click) with Illustrator you have to define Illustrator in the *"Open with.."* field on right click *Preferences* menu of any SVG file. Dont forget to tick the bottom box to always allow opening this file type with Illustrator.

Comment: Tnx a lot!!:)))